# SQLTableCheckOperator is not working, showing missing right perentesis

Tags: airflow

I am trying to use the SQL table check operator to check if a table has more than 1 rule.

But it return error “Missing right parenthesis”

N/b: Connecting to oracleDB

```
test_gtfm_operator = SQLTableCheckOperator(

            task_id="test_gtfm",
            conn_id='airflow_db',
            table=table ,
            checks={
                "row_count_check": {"check_statement":"COUNT(*) > 0", }
                },
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when connecting to an Oracle DB. I don't know if you figured this out already, but it actually seems to be an incompatibility with Oracle's syntax, which does not like `AS` before a table name. I got around this by defining a custom operator class:

```py
class OracleTableCheckOperator(SQLTableCheckOperator):
    sql_check_template = """
    SELECT '{check_name}' AS check_name, MIN({check_name}) AS check_result
    FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN {check_statement} THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS {check_name}
          FROM {table} {partition_clause}) sq
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.sql = f"SELECT check_name, check_result FROM ({self._generate_sql_query()}) check_table"
```